# How to run dynamic SQL query in Entity Framework 7 that auto-maps to Entities (SqlQuery<T>)?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have an existing app that I am trying to upgrade from MVC5/EF6 to MVC6/EF7.  We dynamically create some of our SQL tables, and as a result, have made use of the

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery
```

method to automatically map to entities that we use throughout our application.

This method seems to have gone away (i.e. not part of 
     Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Database    ) in EF7 (or is not yet implemented).  Are there plans to re-implement this method in EF7 or is there another way to accomplish this?  Our project is kind of dead in the water until we figure this out.

***Edited on May 20, 2015***

I've been trying to make this work with FromSql, since that's what's available in Beta4, but no matter what combination of concatenated string, parameters I try, I keep getting different versions of an "Incorrect Syntax near @xxxvariable" message.

```
var results = Set<AssessmentResult>().FromSql("dbo.GetAssessmentResults @FieldA='Data1', @FieldB='Data2', @UserId = 2303"); 
var results2 = Set<AssessmentResult>().FromSql("dbo.GetAssessmentResults @FieldA= {0}", intData);
```

Both of these calls result in

```
"Incorrect syntax near '@FieldA'"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We recently introduced the `.FromSql()` extension method on `DbSet`. It has the added benefit that you can continue composing LINQ on top of it.

```cs
var customers = db.Customers
    .FromSql("SELECT * FROM Customer")
    .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("A"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Is that a part of 7.0.0.0-beta3?  Or is it even newer than that?  Also, the SqlQuery method can specify a Type as its first parameter.  I wouldn't have a DbSet available to be able to use this method.  I currently dynamically create each Type using Reflection.

Is there a way I can use what you mentioned above with this sort of approach?  Again, I really appreciate your input.  Thanks!

Comment: `FromSql` is not available in beta 3. For the time being, `FromSql` is the only way we can run plain SQL statement.