# EF7 beta8 FromSQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

For the EF7 FromSQL parsing sql query to get the entity list.

```
var accounts = _context.Set<Account>().FromSql("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Account WITH  
(NOLOCK)").ToList();
```

this above will return the entity list, but for certain condition.

```
var report = _context.Set<AccountReport>().FromSql("SELECT a.Id, a.Username, p.Item,
p.Quantity FROM Account AS a WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Purchase AS p WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
p.AccountId = a.Id WHERE p.CreatedOn BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-12-01').ToList();
```

The model "AccountReport" is not an entity model, it will encounter with this error message.

**Error**:

> Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.ModelItemNotFoundException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The entity type 'AccountReport' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

Comment: Is AccountReport in your model?

Comment: AccountReport is a model, but not an entity model. This because it need to aggregate some data from multiple table.

Comment: But if it is not part of your model, FromSQL will not work

Answer (score 0):

This should help when you try to fetch data which is not bound to DBSet.

[EF7 Fetch dynamic data, not bound to DBSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1050214/Entity-Framework-How-to-retrieve-dynamic-data)

Other way is to write LINQ as done here

[Linq to fetch dynamic data in EF7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413120/how-to-run-dynamic-sql-query-in-entity-framework-7-that-auto-maps-to-entities-s)

Answer (score 0):

In select query you have to select the all the non nullable column of AccountReport since  the select query is assigned to the entity AccountReport .